# count how many rows from parent table exist in other 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, left-join

I have a parent table where all of the PROTOCOLs and LOTs have to exist if they are found in another 2 tables.
I need to find out how many of these PROTOCOLs and LOTs are in the other two tables: tbl2, tbl3:

```
           parent       tbl2       tbl2
|--------|----------|------------|----------|
|PROTOCOL| 150      |  132       |  71      |
|--------|----------|------------|----------|
| LOT    | 845      |  724       |  621     |
|--------|----------|------------|----------|
```

So far what i got, is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PROTOCOL
FROM parent L
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PROTOCOL
    FROM tbl2
) E
ON L.PROTOCOL = E.PROTOCOL
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PROTOCOL
    FROM tbl3
) N
ON L.PROTOCOL = N.PROTOCOL
```

I wanted to make `PROTOCOL` work before I include `LOT`, but I can't seem to do this one either.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you use subselects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation, I think the following should do it:

```
     SELECT COUNT(distinct l.protocol) as parent
           ,COUNT(distinct e.protocol) as tbl2
           ,COUNT(distinct n.protocol) as tbl3
    FROM parent L
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 E on L.protocol=E.protocol
    LEFT JOIN tbl3 N on L.protocol=N.protocol
    UNION ALL 
    --same for the LOP count
```

Comment: Thank you @Kiril. This worked. How would I add LOT Counts as a second row?

Comment: `the above query`     `UNION ALL`      `the LOT Counts qry`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct p.protocol)
FROM PARENT p INNER JOIN tbl2 t2 ON p.protocol = t2.protocol 
INNER JOIN tbl3 t3 ON p.protocol = t2.protocol
```

or this:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct p.protocol)
FROM PARENT p 
WHERE p.protocol IN (SELECT protocol FROM tbl2)
AND p.protocol IN (SELECT protocol FROM tbl3)
```